# Does windows phone 7 have a similar component likes UITableview in iPhone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Does windows phone 7 have a similar component likes UITableview in iPhone?
I am trying to find an api mapping published by Microsoft, but to no avail.

I welcome any comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet would be to bind the data to a ListBox.

[Here is an example](http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/07/25/listbox-on-wp7/).

Answer (score 1):

You may be interrested in http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/

It includes details on getting up to speed on Windows Phone 7 development for people familliar with developing for other platforms. (Including iOS.)

Answer (score 0):

Tim is correct that you will most likely end up using a ListBox, but here is a bit of a longer answer:

I believe you are referring to the [iOS to Windows Phone API mapping tool](http://wp7mapping.interoperabilitybridges.com/), which helps map common iOS APIs to their Windows Phone equivalents. Unfortunately in this case it will [not provide a direct answer](http://wp7mapping.interoperabilitybridges.com/home/Search/uitableview) to your question, as [iOS and Windows Phone take different approaches to the UI layer](http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/blog/Pages/iphoneappdevelopment.aspx):

> Apple enforces a strict MVC pattern on each of its views. In fact, they provide a set of base view controller classes which already support much of the behaviors you see in typical iPhone applications. The most common of these include UITableViewController, UINavigationViewController, UITabBarController and the standard UIViewController.

Windows phone 7 does not require you to use an MVC pattern, and therefore does not include the standard views that are available in iOS. Instead it is left up to you to choose and implement whatever UI pattern that you choose. Many choose the [MVVM Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Video/gg241309), but even then there are multiple toolkits you can use ([This one](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) seems pretty popular).

To start, with most users will just use the graphical designer built into Visual Studio to drag and drop controls onto each page of their application. If you want to learn more I recommend watching the [Windows Phone 7 Development for Absolute Beginners](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners) series or [31 days of Windows Phone 7](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/09/30/31-days-of-windows-phone-7/) series. Most [Silverlight XAML layout and APIs](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Silverlight_Basics__XAML_and_Layout.aspx) techniques are available in Windows Phone, so [31 days of Silverlight](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2009/06/30/31-thirty-one-days-of-silverlight/) may also help.